# Trying to copy a datagridview from one form to another

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview

I know my title is a little strange. Let me explain. I am trying to "merge" two databases, one we house locally and one that is at another facility with the hopes of avoiding our admin group having to duplicate entry through separate forms. I have the source for a webservice that connects to the offsite database and I can enter data. What I am trying to do is expand that source by adding in our own database and copying our data to theirs. Hope this makes sense.

Anyway,

So both the local and offsite forms have datagridviews attached to them. I can currently copy the contents of the first row to their form for entry, but I am getting errors when it attempts to go to the second row. Here is my code:

```
  Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To VRMAdDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
            'For Each row As DataGridViewRow In VRMAdDataGridView.Rows

            'myrow = VRMAdDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index
            frmcall.dgvRMAItems.Rows(i).Cells("cItemID").Value = Me.VRMAdDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn5").Value
            frmcall.dgvRMAItems.Rows(i).Cells("cExpectedSerialNumber").Value = Me.VRMAdDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2").Value
            frmcall.dgvRMAItems.Rows(i).Cells("cNotes").Value = Me.VRMAdDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3").Value

            'Format Type codes from FW to match Utica
            Select Case Me.VRMAdDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn6").Value
                Case "Repair"
                    frmcall.dgvRMAItems.Rows(i).Cells("cRequestedAction").Value = "Repair"
                Case "RTS"
                    frmcall.dgvRMAItems.Rows(i).Cells("cRequestedAction").Value = "Rtn/Stock"
                Case "Repair !!RUSH!!"
                    frmcall.dgvRMAItems.Rows(i).Cells("cRequestedAction").Value = "Rush Repair"

            End Select


            ' myrowval = row.Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn5").Value
            ' MsgBox(myrowval, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Prod_Code")
            'Do Something
        Next
```

When I try to run the code I receive the following error:

{"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"}

Answer (score 1):

You should manipulate the underlying datasources, not UI elements (DataGridViews in this case). For example, your DataSource is a DataTable. Then just use [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) method to get a copy. Then set a DataSource of that other DataGridView. If you need something more than a copy, it's definitely going to be more simple to work with a series of DataRow objects.

Comment: Thanks for that. I should mention at this point that the datatables are not the same and I am having to manipulate the data that is in our local copy to make it conform to how it is being entered in the offsite database.

Comment: @DewaynePinion: Which is completely okay, your DataTable does not have to be bound. It can represent an in-memory only copy of data, which gets populated from a CSV file, computed from existing data or acquired otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Neolisk, I will look into that tomorrow and will update from there :)